# MySQL Like On One Row, Like on Multiple Row INNER JOINED Tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables on my database as follows:

```
kill_list
+-----------------------------------------------+
| id |  batch_name  | execution_date  | status  |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 1  |Shallow Minds |   2013-10-29    |    0    |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 2  | Brain Dead   |   2013-10-26    |    1    |
+-----------------------------------------------+

kill_list_designation
+------------------------------+
| id |  kill_list    | target  |
+------------------------------+
| 1  |      1        |    1    |
+------------------------------+
| 2  |      1        |    2    |
+------------------------------+
| 3  |      2        |    4    |
+------------------------------+
| 4  |      1        |    5    |
+------------------------------+
| 5  |      2        |    3    |
+------------------------------+

targets
+--------------------------------+
| id |  firstname    | lastname  |
+--------------------------------+
| 1  |      John     |  Smith    |
+--------------------------------+
| 2  |      Mark     |  Hall     |
+--------------------------------+
| 3  |      Kim      |  Stone    |
+--------------------------------+
| 4  |      Rob      |  Reeds    |
+--------------------------------+
| 5  |      Ivan     |  Gay      |
+--------------------------------+
```

Right now, I am only able to do a search on query on the kill_list table with this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM kill_list 
WHERE batch_name     LIKE CONCAT('%', 'query term', '%') 
   OR execution_date LIKE CONCAT('%', 'query term') 
   OR status         LIKE CONCAT('%', 'query term', '%');
```

In this query, I can only get the details of the kill list, but not the targets included in the list. If I search for "**Mark**", the query should give me the details of `kill_list` #1 where Mark is included.

How can I be able to get all the targets for the kill list by entering a term? The query must be able to compare the term to the names of the targets. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM kill_list A
JOIN kill_list_designation B ON A.id=B.kill_list
JOIN targets C ON B.target=C.id
WHERE A.batch_name LIKE CONCAT('%', 'query term', '%') 
   OR A.execution_date LIKE CONCAT('%', 'query term') 
   OR A.status LIKE CONCAT('%', 'query term', '%')
   OR C.firstname LIKE CONCAT('%', 'query term', '%') 
   OR C.laststname LIKE CONCAT('%', 'query term', '%');
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create Join for it.

A simple join for this structure will be as follows,

```
SELECT kl.*, kld.*,t.* FROM kill_list as kl,kill_list_designation as kld,targets as t
WHERE 
kl.id = kld.kill_list
AND
kld.target = t.id
```

To search for mark specifically you can use

```
SELECT kl.*, kld.*,t.* FROM kill_list as kl,kill_list_designation as kld,targets as t
WHERE 
kl.id = kld.kill_list
AND
kld.target = t.id
AND 
t.firstname like 'Mark'
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32af7/6)